# How to get a String from a Jframe (textfield) and put on another jFrame (txtArea)? - Netbeans - Well Explained

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, textfield

it's my first post in here, but you have been helping me indirectly in many ways. But this kind of thing, like the title says, I still can't figure out.
I think I don't need to say I'm a noob in such a thing, and any kind of help would be great =] .. By the way, I'm using netbeans (Java).

So, here's my problem:

- I have a jFrame1 with 3 textFields.
- Also, in this jFrame1, I have a button that should do the following:
  +Look through the whole 3 textFields and only select the words that are     between "" and/or between **. Other words should not be used. Also, this button should redirect me to jFrame2.
- In the other jFrame2, the 'special' words found in the 3 textFields (jFram1), should be put in there, inside a jTextArea1.

And that's where I'm lost. Because I can't find a way to get these 'special' words and throw them in there.

Let me post the code in here, so you guys can take a closer look to what I'm doing right/wrong:

//Below, the Jframe1

```
public class JFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public TxtFieldsQuotationMarks tfqm = new TxtFieldsQuotationMarks();
        public TxtFieldsAsterisk tfa = new TxtFieldsAsterisk();

public JFrame1() 
            {                
            initComponents();           
            }
```

//Below, the classes I created to support the textFields in JFrame1

```
public class TxtFieldsQuotationMarks 
  {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public String field3;
  }

public class TxtFieldsAsterisk 
  {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public String field3;
  }
```

//Bellow, the function that should do the trick (of finding those 'special words')

```
private String Get_Fields_FindWords()(String Value)
{
    if  (Value.isEmpty())
    {
       return "";
    }
    else
    {
      String AuxStr = Value.substring(Value.indexOf('"'),Value.length());
      return AuxStr.substring(1, AuxStr.indexOf('"'));
    }
}


private String Get_Fields_Asterisk_FindWords(String Value)
{
    if  (Value.isEmpty())    

    {
       return "";
    }
    else
    {
      String AuxStr = Value.substring(Value.indexOf('*'),Value.length());
      return AuxStr.substring(1, AuxStr.indexOf('*'));
    }
}
```

//Below, the button in JFrame1, that should find the words and open the JFrame2 for me with those words (Quotation Marks on top and Asterisks below it)

```
private void btnJFrame1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {

    Get_Fields_FindWords();
    Get_Fields_Asterisks_FindWords();
    JFrame2 jf2 = new JFrame2();
        jf2.setVisible(true);
   }
```

//Below, the methods I tried to implement, in order to save the 'special words' in the textFields (this is also in the JFrame1)

```
public void Get_Fields()
    {
        fields.field1 = Return_StringQuotationMarks(txtField1.getText());
        fields.field2 = Retorna_StringAspas(txtField2.getText());
        fields.field3 = Retorna_StringAspas(txtField3.getText());
    }

public void Get_Fields_Asterisk()
    {
        fields_asterisk.field1 = Return_StringAsterisk(txtField1.getText());
        fields_asterisk.field2 = Return_StringAsterisk(txtField2.getText());
        fields_asterisk.field3 = Return_StringAsterisk(txtField3.getText());
    }
```

//Finally, here's the second JFrame (Jframe2), with the textArea (textArea)

```
public class JFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        TxtFieldsQuotationMarks tfqm = new TxtFieldsQuotationMarks();
        TxtFieldsAsterisk tfa = new TxtFieldsAsterisk();


        public JFrame2() 
        {
            initComponents();
        }
}
```

---

That's pretty much it, guys. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do and can help me somehow. I really need this thing done as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think you can pass the words founds by constructor of JFrame2. For example:

```
private void btnJFrame1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    JFrame2 jf2 = new JFrame2(
                              Get_Fields(txtField1.getText()),
                              Get_Fields(txtField2.getText()),
                              Get_Fields(txtField3.getText()),
                              Get_Fields_Asterisk(txtField1.getText()),
                              Get_Fields_Asterisk(txtField1.getText()),
                              Get_Fields_Asterisk(txtField1.getText()));
    jf2.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the constructor of JFrame2:

```
public JFrame2(String field1, String field2, String field3, String asterisk1, String asterisk2, String asterisk3) 
{
    initComponents(field1, field2, field3, asterisk1, asterisk2, asterisk3);
}
```

Then you can initializate components in JFrame2 with the values searched in JFrame1.
You don't need to save it somewhere you only need it in initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick answer, PhoneixS! I'll try it and then I'll let you know what happened.

Comment: No problem. We are here for help others.

Comment: it is easy to initilize it like this.
But suppose you also have a Save button in jFrame2 and it return some values in it to jFrame1. How can you do that?

Comment: Myabe you can pass a reference to JFrame1 in the constructor of JFrame2 so you can access it from JFrame2 when needed.